# How to shuffle an array of N size without any imports

Tags: java, arrays, math, random, shuffle

The goal is to shuffle an array of N size. No imports can be used within the code. i.e. Random

I am able to do it with ease using imports as shown below although these are forbidden.

```
private static void shuffleArray(int[] array)
  {
      int index, temp;
      Random random = new Random();
      for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
      {
          index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
          temp = array[index];
          array[index] = array[i];
          array[i] = temp;
      }
  }
```

End goal is to shuffle the array in a random order. Pseudo-random is perfectly fine.

Comment: Consider using `Math.random()` to get a random index.

Comment: Math.random() cannot be used. Is there a possible way to get a random number bewtween 0 - n without the use of this?

Comment: No imports? No problem! Change `Random random = new Random();` to `java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();` and remove the import statements.

Comment: @Javasaurusrex: Sure, you need to implement your own (pseudo) random number generator. The linear congruential one is not too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int []a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++)
{
    int index = (int)(System.nanoTime() % a.length);
    int tmp = a[index];
    a[index] = a[i];
    a[i] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: The result of nanotime [does not necessarily exhibit nanosecond resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()). It is, for example, permissible for the value to only change [every 10 millseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) and therefore every call during your loop may produce the same index.  An explicit pseudorandom generator should be used.